# Geometric symbols alongside input filter capacitors on 1960's amplifier schematic

Tags: power-supply, schematics, vacuum-tube

Capacitors C1, C2 and C3 are accompanied on this schematic by a semicircle, square and triangle symbol respectively. I'd expect the meaning of unusual symbols to be explained on the same drawing; they aren't, so perhaps they belong to a convention I've not yet encountered.

[image]

[Link to source of schematic](http://hhscott.com/pdf/335.pdf)

Edit: Encountered these same symbols on a capacitor in the Heathkit IM-58 Harmonic Distortion Meter [though the symbols don't appear in the schematic]:
[image]

Comment: You should link to the source of the diagram and take note; this isn't a well drawn diagram so don't expect logic in the symbols.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

These are multiple electrolytic capacitors in a single package. The package would have more than the usual 2 pins, one for each capacitor and a shared ground pin. Each non-ground pin would have such a symbol next to it to identify it. The markings on the side would then state the symbols and their respective capacitances/voltages.

Here's a picture of such a capacitor. (Source: Myself).

[image: Multiple capacitors in single package]

Comment: You will probably also find these symbols stamped on the terminals themselves if you look at the base of the capacitor. I'll try to find a photo.

Comment: As it happens, I finally did! [Edited question to show findings].